# How to add csrf token to ajax request

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have issues adding csrf to ajax request. I'm using thymeleaf on client side with spring-boot/spring security. Spring security wouldn't allow the request because csrf-token is missing.  Here is my code for ajax

```
function bits(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var selected = document.getElementById("product").value;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        var result= JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
        var length = result.length;
        for(i=0; i<length; i++){

           console.log(result[k].spid);
        }
    }

};

 xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/bids?q="+selected,  true);
 xhttp.send();
```

}

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I modified @Prakash Hari Sharma's solution and had the following code that worked for me. Note, th: prefix if using Thymeleaf.

--Header section

```
<meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Ajax script function

```
...
...
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"); 
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
...
...
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/bids?q="+selected,  true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader(header, token);
xhttp.send();
```

Hope this helps someone too.

Answer (score 13):

As a complementary to @EdwardoS answer, after you add meta tags to the `<head>` element:

Thymeleaf:

```
<meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

JSP:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

...you can then do what is suggested in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) and have all your future ajax to include `csrf`:

```
$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function (e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

In spring documentation, it is also suggested that you do not use csrf token in GET requests for security reasons

> "The ability to scope which requests receive the token helps guard
>   against leaking the CSRF token to a third party."

You can therefore filter to pass token only for POST requests with following manner:

```
$(function() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        if (options.type == "POST") {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        }
    });
});
```

The meta tags in `<head>` element would be the same as in previous answers:

```
<meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Store CSRF Token in your jsp meta tags

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

and add values of csrf token in ajax request

```
var elementToken = document.querySelector('meta[property="_csrf"]');
var token = elementToken && elementToken.getAttribute("content");
var elementHeader = document.querySelector('meta[property="_csrf_header"]');
var header = elementHeader && elementHeader.getAttribute("content");
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/bids?q="+selected,  true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(header, token);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: I appied the above code and still got forbiden error. Then I replaced all the variable lines in the code above with:                                                                                                var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");                               And problem was solved. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For Thymeleaf, just prefix th: to 'name' and 'content' in the metas above. I was using Thymleaf, and that's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

below you can find my code to use ajax with csrf. I use Spring Security too.

```
    // In your JSP meta tags
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

    // In your javascript
    // CSRF Variables
    var _tc = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var _hc = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");


    // Header
    var headersStomp = {};
    headersStomp[_hc] = _tc;

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(_hc, _tc);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Spring Security's CSRF Token into a Javascript variable called `MyApp.csrfToken`.

In your **JSP**, add the flowing script to call the init function once your document is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
       var state = document.readyState;
       if (state == 'complete') {
         fnInit("${_csrf.parameterName}", "${_csrf.token}"); 
       }
    }​;
</script>
```

In your **JS** file, define the `fnInit` function

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
function fnInit(csrfParam, csrfToken) {
  MyApp.csrfToken = {
      param : csrfParam,
      value : csrfToken
  }
}
```

Now you have the token **ready to use** in any ajax call

```
...
...
xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/bids?q="+selected + "&"+ MyApp.csrfToken.param+"="+ MyApp.csrfToken.value,  true);
xhttp.send();
```

PS: **No need** for jQuery, it is pure JavaScript.